# 'if'-'else' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a simple `if` - `else` construct that operates with data grid filterind. Like this:

```
if (_r1 <= _r3 && _r3 <= _r2) {
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

where `_r1, _r2, _r3` and numbers. It has both `true` and `false`. Is it possible to rewrite this construction that it will has only for example `true` branch and will go to the else branch by default?

P.S. `(if ... ? ... : ...)` is not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
return _r1 <= _r3 && _r3 <= _r2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (_r1 <= _r3 && _r3 <= _r2) {
   return true;
}
return false;
```